# android webview form post

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

I want to write a form proxy in my app. The html file is stored locally and the form code is

```
<form action="custom" method="POST" />
```

My custom `WebView` should handle the **action** tag differently. So **custom** should be redirected to a different URL, depending on user settings in my app.

I wrote a custom `WebView` and where I override `postUrl`, but it is never fired. I also tried a custom `WebViewClient` and override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, but this is also not fired.

Which method should I override to change my post url and the `CONTENT-TYPE` for my formular?

Edit: I found https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9122 and I thing nobody found a solution for this problem. That's really bad.

Answer (score 0):

Inject javascript into WebView right after the page is loaded and change action of the form using it. You can simply inject javascript by calling webView.loadUrl("javascript:...");

Comment: I didn't want to `WebView` to send the form data. My app should send the data, because I want to handle error messages etc. in it.

Comment: In that case use similar technique, inject javascript, but do not change action attribute and add onsubmit with function from your own JavascriptInterface to the form instead. Via JavascriptInterface, you can catch submitting of the form and act accordingly.

Comment: This could be a possible way. I'll check it out.